# Cannot make a POST request with x-www-form-urlencoded c# to Satisfy OAuth

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, oauth, google-api

I'm attempting to work through set 4 of the Google OAuth API: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/guides/auth/server-side-web-apps.

I suspect I'm doing something wrong with the "x-www-form-urlencoded" part of this code. The error I'm getting is not very descriptive though, and after trying to work through this I am hitting a wall here. Any thoughts on where I might be going wrong here would be amazing

I'm getting this error:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_request",
  "error_description": "\nYou can\u0026#39;t sign in to this app because it doesn\u0026#39;t comply with Google\u0026#39;s OAuth 2.0 policy for keeping apps secure.\n\nYou can let the app develope
r know that this app doesn\u0026#39;t comply with one or more Google validation rules.\n  "
}
```

With this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var endpoint = new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token");

            var payload = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("code", "4/..."),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", "..."),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", "..."),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("redirect_uri", "http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Foauth2callback&"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "authorization_code"),
            });
            
            payload.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            var result = client.PostAsync(endpoint, payload).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the C# methods but your `redirect_uri` probably should **not** terminate with `&`. The form encoded fields are separate by `&`. You could try outputting the payload as a string to confirm that you're getting something similar to Google's doc example. Generally, unless you've a compelling reason, it's much easier (and requires less ongoing maintenance|support) to use one of Google's client libraries.

Comment: Changing localhost gave the error "invalid grant". Seems like progress though?

Comment: {
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Bad Request"
}

Comment: I'd be so happy to use their library, but they have almost no examples for .NET so it feels just as hard

Comment: Yes, you're getting there. I'd re-review the prior steps and ensure you've not made a prior mistake. There should be plenty of folks on here who can help you with problems using the client libraries and, in my experience (former Googler), you'll save yourself a bunch of hassle, when you use the library. See this question :-)